# Is there a way to disable the hit marker?

Tags: fallout-4

I have Fallout 4 on the PlayStation 4 and although I have found the option to disable the crosshairs entirely, I have not been able to find an option to disable the hit marker effect. Is it possible with or without mods?

Comment: Pretty sure you need a mod for that. There's several on nexus.